# Translating WIGeoEU projection from ArcGIS to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a Layer with this projection in ArcGIS:

> PROJCS["WIGeoEU",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",10.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",40.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",60.0],PARAMETER["Central_Parallel",30.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Whenever I try to open it with QGIS, this layer is somewhere out of space and I can't display it together with any other layers which should overlay.

I try to convert this by hand to the format QGIS is using without any success.

That's how the description of the shape looks in QGIS:

Layer Spatial Reference System:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=40 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Is anyone able to help me with my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of CENTRAL_PARALLEL = 30.0 has got lost in the conversion.

Try lat_0=30 and see if it fits.

Is the datasource publicly available?

No need to be frustrated, you are not the first one: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3191

Unfortuantely, the ticket has not got much attention :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've submitted a [patch for the ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3191), hopefully someone will review it.  I don't have much for test data, a real world example and data set would be nice.

Comment: Fixed: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3191#comment:7, thanks for the pretty-fying my link underdark.

Comment: It will hopefully find its way into the QGIS 2.0 release too.

Comment: Assuming 1.10.1 will be out in the next few weeks, and QGIS 2.0 a few weeks after, it should make the release.